# Querying Array in MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I am currently developing a drag drop item box using Jquery. The Jquery picks the item ID's in the box and sends it as an array to the calculcation page (calc.php).

Using this arrays variables (item IDs) I wish to pull the price from the database using a query / function to do so.

I feel my current code is a little basic and may be over-complicating things or worse not working which has been a problem so far.

**Draggable Jquery**

```
 var full = $("#calcid > .drag").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("id");
}).get();
var listurl = "calc.php?a="+full;
$("#itemnotice").load(listurl);
},
```

The following code lists the ID's within "calcid" and then shoved them into an array. This array is then sent to calc.php and loaded into the div itemnotice (where the price will be displayed).

**The calc.php page is as follows:**

```
<?php
$grablist = str_split(mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_GET['a'])));
foreach ($grablist as $newlist) {
$costquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `values_catalogue` WHERE `id` IN($newlist)")or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($costquery);
$newtotal = $cost_cookie + $row['value'];
}
echo "$newtotal coins";
?>
```

Calc.php works for the first drag/dropped item but afterwards I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Would really like to streamline the above code and would be thankful for the help  receive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming IDs are numeric,

```
$ids = implode(',', $newlist);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `values_catalogue` WHERE `id` IN($ids)");
```

the above code will work.

Suggestion here: mysql_* apis are deprecated. Switch to mysqli_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ids = join(',', $newlist);
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `values_catalogue` WHERE `id` IN($ids)");
```